# WhenAll doesn't give much gains with respect to performance

Tags: c#, performance, async-await, task-parallel-library

While I understand `.WhenAll()` truly gives the power to exploit async nature of functions, but in reality I don't see much gains.
Few details about my setup:
SQL Server DB (S3 tier DB), C# WebAPI, Azure cloud.

Code:

```
public Task DeleteAsync(Someclass obj)
{   
   //Some complex operations
   //multiple DB reads
   //some complex operations
   //pushing messages to bus 
   //All above operations are mostly async
}

callingFunction1()
{
   List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach (var id in idList.Ids)
   {
      listOfTasks.Add(_SomeService.DeleteAsync(obj));
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
}

callingFunction2()
{
   List<Exception> exceptions = new List<Exception>();
   foreach (var id in idList.Ids)
   {    
      try
      {
         await _SomeService.DeleteAsync(obj)
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         exceptions.Add(ex);
      }
    }  
}
```

I'm really surprised to see that `callingFunction2()` is performing slightly better than `callingFunction1()` which is truly async.

Can someone care to explain why is this happening?

Comment: Async/await isn't intended to be primarily a **performance** enhancing feature - it's really more about **scalability on the server**, e.g. ability to handle more requests and more efficiently on a server. The performance of each individual request isn't improved by this

Comment: Is it possible your `DeleteAsync` or something within is acquiring a lock that just makes everything serial?

Comment: @AKX possible, biz logic is huge and it uses uow, dbcontext etc

Comment: There is nothing to answer here, there is no reliable benchmarking results, and the actual workload is hidden and unquestionable. So its hard to say if what you are seeing is actually correct, or what you are doing is sane

Comment: Also note that what you've done here is, in non-async terms, the chaos equivalent of starting N threads/tasks each performing a `Delete`; if `_SomeService` isn't designed for concurrency, this could crash horribly, and even if it works: performing lots of concurrent out-of-process operations *may* actually *degrade* performance; the ideal case here would be: a batching API that takes N ids to delete (any time you don't immediately `await` an awaitable, you're risking potential concurrency problems, although since awaitables *can* complete synchronously, it isn't *guaranteed* to be concurrent)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you. Your comment clarifies my confusion.

Answer (score -1):

The performance is only really impactful when you start working with very large data sets, as your program scales up and starts managing larger data sets you'll begin to see the performance of callingFunction1() consistently out performing callingFunction2().

Small data sets aren't very intensive and so you wont see any significant improvements, if any.

Comment: I'd say that's a lot of speculation on points pointed out in comments for the OP, and not really the answer. There's no clarity in OP on the size of workload as well as on implementation details (especially scalability) of `DeleteAsync`.